# StackOverFlow when fetching a Set in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting a `StackOverFlowException` when fetching a Set of entities in a `ManyToMany` relationship.

The exception is thrown in mapping layer using `ModelMapper` (using `@JsonIgnore` has not solved the problem). However, debugging I can se the stackoverflow in the collection field.

Here below is my code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_child")
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class AChildEntity extends AbstractEntity{

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal value;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "a_child")
    private final Set<AnocherChildEntity> menu = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "another_child")
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class AnotherChildEntity extends AbstractEntity{

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "another_child_a_child",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "another_child_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_child_id")
    )
    private final Set<AChildEntity> aChild = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_id")
    private OtherEntity other;
}
```

In my `PersistenSet` I get: 
`Exception occurred: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method..` and the mapping crashes with multiple similar messages in console log:

```
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Comment: EqualsAndHashCode: this generates equals and hashCode that call equals() and hashCode() on all the fields of the entity. But the fields themselves use EqualsAndHashCode, and refer to their owning entity. So that generates a StackOverflowException. The easiest way to have valid equals and hashCode methods for entities is to not define them at all.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. It was exacly the problem. I removed `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have a cyclic reference problem: AChildEntity references set of AnocherChildEntity and AnocherChildEntity reference set of AChildEntity. So when marshaling it creates an infinite recursion that leads to StackOverFlowError.

User @JsonIgnore on one side, or better use separate DTO classes without cyclic references as interface objects

Comment: As I said, `@JsonIgnore` has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @JBNizet suggested, I have removed the `@EqualsAndHashCode` in both entities and the cyclic reference is gone.